# How to send query parameters and body data in jMeter post request

Tags: node.js, jmeter, performance-testing

I am new to Jmeter please help me in this, i try to do performance test of my nodejs application.And i have one api, for this i have to pass parameters as well as post from .csv file but i am not able to achieve so give your valuable input

Comment: show what you trying to do and failed

Answer (score 20):

1. Put your parameters to "Path" input field
2. Put your request body to "Body Data" input field

   [image: JMeter Request with Parameters]
3. You might also need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type). See [REST API Testing - How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing-how-to-do-it-right) for more details.

Comment: Thank you Demitri, but in this case values will be like hard coding, i want dynamic values

Comment: I really surprises me that you can't specify "Parameters" and "Body Data" at the same time. It means that you have to manually url encode the query parameters you want to send, instead of relying on the checkbox in the Parameters tab.

Comment: Ok, how to add parameters in the "Body Data" input field?

Comment: You have to remove all "Parameters" from the first tab before you can enter the "Body data" tab.